# Access third party application via another application

Tags: windows

I have an idea for a program that needs to communicate with already existing programs.

Here is the scenario:

On the market there is a (or several) CRM software for Windows. Instead of telling the developers of said CRM system to integrate my search application 100%, I would somehow make them only add a simple button in their CRM at an appropriate place.

When clicking this button my application opens up, which basically is a search engine. This application is coded by my developer. From the search results the user will be able to select a result and "post back" the information to the CRM.

Like I mentioned the purpose of this would be for me to ship and control the search application only, not having each CRM company go through and create the same interface each time, and for the CRM software company to only open my application.

Similar to how a javascript widget works on a website. The website itself can not change anything in the widget.

Is this technically possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Any application that runs in windows operating system is capable of start another application to run.

The problem here is exporting your search result into CRM database. When you say your application will be shipped with a particular crm product, I guess your application will be specific to a particular CRM product inorder to post the data in that particular crm product format.

To expand my answer, I need the following information.

```
1. Your targetted crm product technology. ex: CRM product1 built using .NET 4.0
2. Your application technology. ex: C++
3. Integration mechanism supported by CRM product. ex: Webservice call, Website csv upload etc.,
```

EDIT: Based on author comment

I understand from your comment that you are going to write a software and sell it to CRM product company to include your software in their product. Correct me if I am wrong.

In that case you need to define your format and integration mechanism. You can build your application to support different types of integration. Ex: a) Webservice - REST, JSON, SOAP b) Database - SQL Server, MYSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle c) Website upload - CSV, Tab Delimited, Excel

You can even make your format as generic item. You can provide a screen to map your column with CRM product column.

Once your app support those mechanism its up to the CRM product company to choose the best mechanism and one time setup is required to configure those information. If there is a change happens in future then they have to reconfigure your app.

Comment: I would need something as generic as possible. I am sure that if you compare 10 CRM programs they are all written in different languages.

I know you can open another program. But the problem as you state is to send back the information.

Would it be possible for the CRM provider to program so they can catch the data from my application to theirs? For example a JSON file.

My thought on the solution would be to ship a packed .exe file with my app, which the CRM provider would put in their install.

Comment: Can the CRM software talk to my application on the desktop without sending information back and forth to another server? Can they communicate with eachother?

Example my application, you write in text "ABC" and hit a button, then my applications sends "ABC" to the CRM software which captures this and fills a form.

I think that is where the problem lies.

My application is a graphical interface for a REST webservice. But I don't want every CRM company to create this GUI every time, this is my job.

Comment: Another thing worth looking at might be COM - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model.  It's not very trendy, but many existing applications use it to communicate with component objects.